# How to change the foreground/background colors of a link in a TextView?

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview, background-color

I need to put some links in one `TextView`. For better user experience, I would like to **highlight the links when user click by changing the foreground/background colors of the links**.

I have tried `android:textColorLink` and `TextView.setLinkTextColor(ColorStateList)`, but none of both works.

Any idea?

Comment: is the link just a TextView underlined to look like a link right?

Comment: In fact I did a lot of customization by SpannableString to the content of the TextView. The liked text does have the functionality of a hyperlink. What I need is a way to change the colors while user clicking.

Comment: you what the link color to be changed to just for that moment, when the user click it, i.e it must go back to its previous color on releasing finger fro touch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a best way is using Spannable

```
Spannable sps=(Spannable )tv.getText();
sps.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), start, end, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```